# smbFile setLastModified not working on Windows share

Tags: java, android

I'm using the JCIFS library to copy a JPG from a phone to a Windows share. The file copy works fine, but the `setLastModified` method doesn't have any effect. I have full write permissions to the share in question. Is there any other way of setting the Last Modified date on a file that I have just created?

```
SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(destFileName, auth);
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(sSourceFilePath));
byte[] buf = new byte[16 * 1024 * 1024];
int len;
while ((len = fileInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
    sfos.write(buf, 0, len);
}
fileInputStream.close();
sfos.close();
sFile.setCreateTime(file_modified_date);
sFile.setLastModified(file_modified_date);
```

Comment: I post a similar bug suggestion as follows:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52751083/not-valid-lastmodified-from-smbfile-of-jcifs-library