# not valid lastModified from smbfile of JCIFS library

Tags: android, window, last-modified, jcifs

I suspect that there is a bug in smbfile of JCIFS library  as I get only 
"Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 GMT+08:00 1970" for any dates from getLastModified(); lastModified(); 
when I do a window share to android device. 
I am looping through the exist files and is able to do file copy operation, so mis-spelling of file name or path is not possible.
I want to get one of the filedate of MS Window file , no matter it is the creation date, lastmodified date or accessed date.

```
filedatetime = mWindowFile.getLastModified();
mToAndroidFile.setLastModified(filedatetime);
```

Answer (score 0):

After testing against 2 phones: rooted android with 4.2.2. setLastModified always return false, another android with 7.1.2, setLastModified works .  so whether setLastModified works or not, it depends. Always tested the returned value!

Comment: I use setLastModified() method always throw SmbException, tell me Access is denied.